# Can I modify or preemptively kill a part of running ;-separated compound bash command?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I am running multiple semicolon-separated bash commands:

```
% long-running-command-I-want ; another-command-I-dont
```

The `long-running-command-I-want` is still running; naturally there is no `pid` of the `another-command-I-dont` yet. I'd like to preemptively kill/cancel/prevent from execution the `another-command-I-dont` without killing the `long-running-command-I-want` which I have been waiting for for a while. Can I do that? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run another shell you can find out the PID of the `bash` which is running the program that you want to continue. If this is `bashPID`, then send an interrupt signal with:

```
kill -2 bashPID
```

This will stop the execution of the rest of the command line.

Optionally, in the original shell you can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> to suspend the running program temporarily in background. This would carry on with the rest of the command line, which will be flushed by the interrupt signal. You can then resume the running program with `fg` or `bg`, depending on whether you want it to continue in foreground or background.